# Should I run arch linux through bootcamp?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot-camp

Just a question, I love macs, I love arch linux, is it possible to arch through bootcamp on the el capitan beta?

Answer (score 0):

What I think, you want to ask is. "can I use the boot camp installer for arch Linux?" 
It may be possible, but I would recommend not to do it, because the boot camp installer is not open source, and there is no documentation. if you face any problems, which are very likely to happen, there is no support, and noone in the arch forum would help you.

if you want to ask about Bootcamp in general, the answer is **No**, because Bootcamp includes many drivers, which would be **very** nice if they work, but they are windows drivers. Also the installer reformats your disk in a way windows would like to use, that's not the way arch does want his formatting (eg the Filesystem, Windows want ntfs, most Linux use ext/btrfs/zfs)